# Moving logic from MainActivity to another class in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a simple logic on my app that looks for a certain pitch.
The problem is that the logic is in the OnCreate method of the app (it has to detect the pitch the moment the application is running).
It is a little bit ugly as I plan to add some more logic as the application starts.
Does anyone have any advice of how to move that code to a different class so that it could be invoked from there?
The class still has to access views in the main activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new PitchProcessor(PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, new PitchDetectionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult pitchDetectionResult,
                                AudioEvent audioEvent) {

            final float pitchInHz = pitchDetectionResult.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Float value = pitchInHz;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value.tostring(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }));
    foo = new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher");
    foo.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two options to make your code cleaner.

1. Move all the code in `onCreate()` (except first two lines) into another method, let's say `lookForPitch()`. Then you can call it right in `onCreate()`.
2. If you plan to create more methods that focus on audio processing, you can create separate class, for example `AudioUtils.java`. This util class should contain public static methods, that you can invoke from any place in your code. In case of `onCreate()` you may call it like this: `AudioUtils.lookForPitch()`. Also if you want to handle Views, that are accessible only in your Activity, you can pass them as argument. So your method in `AudioUtils` can look like this:

   ```
   public static void lookForPitch(TextView myTextView) {
       // your code goes here
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Just make it a method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myLongAndSweetMethod();
}

private void myLongAndSweetMethod(){
AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new PitchProcessor(PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, new PitchDetectionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult pitchDetectionResult,
                                AudioEvent audioEvent) {

            final float pitchInHz = pitchDetectionResult.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Float value = pitchInHz;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value.tostring(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }));
    foo = new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher");
    foo.start();
}
```

Then using the [Code folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-folding.html) of Android Studio to hide it.

Comment: Downvoter, please give a reason why you downvoted my post?

Comment: I did not do the down-vote, but i have done too, because what you are doing is like you should tidy up your room and all you do is but your mess inside a cupboard and close its doors.

Comment: So what's wrong with that? OP needs the `onCreate` to look clean, and my answer does what he wants. Code folding is a great tool for this purpose, too.

Comment: Writing clean code cannot be substituted by code folding!

Comment: I agree with Fildor and Ingo

Answer (score -1):

If you want to improve the readability of your code I can recommend the book "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftmanship" by Robert C. Martin (aka Uncle Bob).

This book is really great! It helped me to a lot to make my code more clean and easy to read. It is a book you should have read if you want to be(come) a professional software developer.